# How to set selected radio button in IONIC using angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

```
<ion-list>
<ion-radio ng-model="choice" ng-value="'A'" ng-click='usedGNG("yes")'>Yes</ion-radio>
<ion-radio ng-model="choice" ng-value="'B'" ng-click='usedGNG("no")'>No</ion-radio>
</ion-list>
```

These are the two radio buttons i've created... And now i want to select one of this radio button using angular js script...I've googled it but didn't find the solution or i may not understood it correctly...So please somebody help me out..Thanks for the Help...

Comment: check this angularjs docs - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just update the model of the radio buttons either inside the directive or from the controller.

**JS CODE:**

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])
   .controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.choice = 'Ember';
});
```

**HTML CODE:**

```
<div ng-app="ionicApp" ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
  <ion-list>
    <ion-radio ng-model="choice" ng-value="'Angular'">Angular</ion-radio>
    <ion-radio ng-model="choice" ng-value="'Ember'">Ember</ion-radio>
  </ion-list>
  <button class="button button-dark" ng-click="choice ='Angular'">
     Set Angular
  </button>
</div>
```

[Live Demo @ JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/yk62zsxv/17/)

Comment: Thank you dude...I've seen the examples in google...but you are very clear and specific...thanks for your help...